# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when using ajax

Tags: geoserver, javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to call json data from geoserver, 
but when i try to run it in chrome, it return this following error

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

This is my code,

```
    function initialize(){var urljson='http://localhost:1234/geoserver/Ven/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ven:alamatpuskesmas&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:getJson';

             $.ajax({
                    url :urljson,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                    success: handleJson
                });

        }
        function handleJson(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
```

i am using geoserver 2.4.2, whats wrong with my code?,
when i try to paste the url in chrome/firefox, it return json. .

Comment: You have some syntax error in your JavaScript somewhere. Try looking at the error message again in Chrome, it should follow with a link that points to the error in your code.

Comment: there is no error in my javascript code, 
the only error message in chrome is 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  
error link is at ows:1

i got same error with this post

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79319/geoserver-wfs-get-feature-doesnt-work-syntaxerror-missing-before-statemen?rq=1

Comment: I can not see how geoserver has anything to do with the error here, but I am missing the bigger picture... What is ows?

Comment: The comment I wrote on the other question you are pointing to might be of some help for you.

Comment: finnaly, i try to use php proxy to get the json data. . in its work. .
:)

Comment: In the url try encoding the colon (':') with %3A

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `var urljson` to the following and change `jsonCallback:getJson` to `jsonCallback:parseResponse`, then it should work:

```
var urljson='http://localhost:1234/geoserver/Ven/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ven:alamatpuskesmas&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson';
```

The part that needs to change is the `outputFormat`. It needs to be `text/javascript` and not `json`.

More information can be found in [this](http://www.gaiaresources.com.au/wordpress/json-with-geoserver-and-leaflet/) tutorial.